# How to update .ToList() in Controller to point to a different table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

So to lay the groundwork due to a bug in MySQL for Visual Studio that crashes the Creation Wizard that would otherwise allow for a Code First from Database, I had to manually create a model, and then did 'Add Controller' referencing `WWUpdated` and `WWUpdatedDBContext`. However, a particular line in my controller is causing me issues:

```
return View(db.WWUpdatedSet.ToList());
```

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition. See the inner exception for details.

Inner exception:

> {"Table 'mydb.wwupdateds' doesn't exist"}

And indeed, that table doesn't exist. It exists as `mydb.ww_updated`. So how do I change my code so that it looks up `mydb.ww_updated` instead? I'm guessing when I created the controller EF just appended "s" to the model name which is not what I want. I've tried searching my entire solution for 'mydb.wwupdateds' and came up blank so I'm not sure where/how to change it to reference the right table name.

For reference part of my controller:

```
public class WWUpdatedSetController : Controller
{
    private WWUpdatedDBContext db = new WWUpdatedDBContext();

    // GET: WWUpdatedSet
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.WWUpdatedSet.ToList());
    }
```

Model:

```
public class WWUpdated
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ww { get; set; }

    public string owner { get; set; }

    public string project { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }

}

public class WWUpdatedDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WWUpdated> WWUpdatedSet { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explicitly map your entity class `WWUpdated` to a table in database. So by default it uses the code-first convention of pluralizing the table names. That means it will look for the `WWUpdateds` table instead of `ww_updated` table. So you have to use `Table` annotation or fluent api to map the table explicitly:

```
[Table("ww_updated")]
public class WWUpdated
{
   //...
}
```

or fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<WWUpdated>().ToTable("ww_updated");
}
```